# Ubuntu Server with ubuntu desktop does not have boot record, but it did when it was just basic server

Tags: boot, dual-boot, server, system-installation

The title says it all.

I started by installing "server" with the ubuntu desktop package, and when it finished and rebooted: nothing. It completed full installation, rebooted, and there was no boot record on that hard drive (I have two hard disks, first runs windows 8, second was to be for server).

I looked up tons of info, but most of it related to the Guid partition and the MBR (I know they are different), but short of deleting the whole thing and starting again, there was no good advice. So, I did that. And just installed the "simple server" package. It loaded fine, and even started as it should (in the boot options screen, there it was Sata2-ubuntu option) and it booted to the cmd prompt.

Then, I did the usual [sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop] from cmd prompt and everything ran and completed fine. But... on reboot, it's gone! No Sata2-ubuntu option anymore!

Any ideas anybody? Maybe another desktop (l/k-buntu)? I don't want to keep trial and error-ing it though, that seems silly and a tremendous amount of work. Also, just in case the question comes up, the boot record won't even appear when I set the bios to legacy compatible.

Thanks to anyone who tries to help!